# How to force Visual Studio to check for latest version of floating point nuget dependencies

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm using floating point dependencies for my other projects like below:

```
<PackageReference Include="Farayan.NETCommonSuper" Version="1.0.*" />
```

Version `1.0.*` means latest version of `Farayan.NETCommonSuper` that starts with `1.0.`, but visual studio does not check for latest version on every build.

Imagine I updated module `Farayan.NETCommonSuper` that I need to get reflected into my another module (let's name it `depend module`), currently I need to open `Manage nuget packages` context menu, and update dependency by myself, which removes * version and fix it in .csproj file, then open that .csproj file to revert it back.

Is there any settings or config or script to force vs to check for latest version of a star-versioned dependency?

Comment: Hi Homayoun, any update about this issue?

Comment: Hi @PerryQian-MSFT, I'm busy with another task, In few days, I'll check it, thanks for you reply

Comment: Well. And we will give any support if you want.

Answer (score 2):

### Visual Studio

Right click the solution in Solution Explorer, and select "Restore NuGet Packages"

### dotnet CLI

`dotnet restore --force-evaluate`

### msbuild

`msbuild -t:restore -p:RestoreForceEvaluate=true`

### nuget.exe

`nuget.exe restore -ForceEvaluate`

Comment: I tried all of 3 solutions, although I have 2 version of Farayan.NETCommonUtility (1.0.14000101.113936 and 1.0.14000101.121430), but dependent project (Farayan.CellNumberUtility) (that is dependent on 1.0.14000101.113936), will NOT updated to use 1.0.14000101.121430 after executing command. (in csproj, I referenced version 1.0.* of Farayan.NETCommonUtility [<PackageReference Include="Farayan.NETCommonUtility" Version="1.0.*" />])

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **zivkan**. However, VS IDE detects the float version of the nuget dependency automatically.

To add more detail

> Version 1.0.* means latest version of Farayan.NETCommonSuper that
> starts with 1.0., but visual studio does not check for latest version
> on every build.

Please if you have enabled the two options under **Tools**-->**Options**

[image]

**Also**, you could try this to make a automatic script:

Right-click on your project on the Solution Explorer-->**Properties**-->**Build Event**-->

add like this this under **Pre-build event command line**:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" -t:restore -p:RestoreForceEvaluate=true
```

Click **Build** button and you can get that you want.

Comment: These configs does not work. They obviously will execute for "Missing" packages, but my dependecies are not Missed, they are just DEPRECATED (according to specified floating version)

Comment: How did you rename the latest version of the nuget? Did you use a pre-release version for that? You should provide more info about your nuget version. Also, when you use it, please let all the nuget packages are under your checked nuget package source.

Comment: And from your description, if you also want to use the latest project dependency under the project, you should also make the same `packageversion` for the dependency project.  That is only depended under your pack format.This is the step: Project A references Project B, Project A uses `<PackageVersion>1.0.14000101.113936</PackageVersion>`, also add this for Project B. Then, pack it, Project A and its dependency project uses the same version `1.0.14000101.113936`. You  can check it under the `xxx.nuspec` under Project A.nupkg.

Comment: If you want to use version `1.0.14000101.121430`, also add `<PackageVersion>1.0.14000101.121430</PackageVersion>` into `Project A` and `Project B`. Then ,repack the two projects. And that `Project A.1.0.14000101.121430.nupkg` uses `Project B.1.0.14000101.121430.nupkg`. You can check the `xxx.nuspec` file under `Project A.1.0.14000101.121430.nupkg` file to get that. And then use floating version so that you can get what you want.